# TextMate 2: Identify opening tag when closing tag is typed

Tags: textmate

First let me say that I have auto closing tags turned off and I like it that way.

When I had TextMate v1 installed and I typed a closing parentheses or bracket, for example, the opening one would do a quick flash.

Now I upgraded to TextMate 2 and it no longer does that unless I use the keyboard back arrow, then it will, but I can't get it to flash while I actually do the typing.

```
function some_function($this) {

  if ($this == 1) {

    echo 'that';

  }

} // When this is typed, the opening bracket would automatically flash
```

Comment: Did this also happen in TextMate v2 before you turned off auto closing tags?